# Upload pdf files to telegram bot with python

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I was trying to upload pdf files to telegram bot with python but it is not working. Where is my mistake?

```
def textbooks(update,context):
    path = r"C:\Users\Ya'we\Downloads\Python Practice Book (en)(1).pdf"

    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path), 'r') as input_file:
        content = input_file.read()
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    return context.bot.send_document(chat_id, input_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues in your code snippets:

1. `path` is already an absolute Path, so joining it with the current directory will give an invalid path
2. the file should be opened as `'rb'` rather than `'r'`
3. You read the files content into the `content` variable, but never use that variable
4. the call to `bot.send_message` happens outside the context manager (`with open(…)`), so `input_file` is a *closed* file on that line and the contents can't be read by PTB.

Please also have a look at PTBs [wiki section on sending files](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#posting-files).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Answer (score 0):

This might help https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Working-with-Files-and-Media

Referring to the above link if you change your code as below it should work.

```
def textbooks(update,context):
    path = r"C:\Users\Ya'we\Downloads\Python Practice Book (en)(1).pdf"
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    return context.bot.send_document(chat_id,document=open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path), 'rb'))
```