# I want to retrieve callback query and call another function which also have another buttons

Tags: python-telegram-bot

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
"""Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
keyboard = [
[
InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2'),
]
]

```
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Comment: Hey. Please read the "how to ask" guides that I pointed you to in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000838.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.